# How to order images, when uploading to strapi media library?

Tags: reactjs, image, next.js, multipartform-data, strapi

I have a post car form with drag and drop file input.

Everything works fine. But when I upload photos to the strapi, the order of the images changes, they are uploading by file size from larger to smaller, as I understood.

How to upload them not by size, but by name, for example ?

| Images in state | Images in strapi |
| --- | --- |
| 1) id - 1, size - 20 | 1) id - 3, size - 30 |
| 2) id - 3, size - 30 | 2) id - 1, size - 20 |
| 3) id - 2, size - 10 | 3) id - 2, size - 10 |

I have acceptedFiles state where uploaded files are stored

```
const [acceptedFiles, setAcceptedFiles] = useState<FileWithPreview[]>([]);
```

When form is submited I create car and add to it images

```
...
const uploadFormData = new FormData();

uploadFormData.append("ref", "api::car.car");
uploadFormData.append("refId", `${res.data.data.id}`);
uploadFormData.append("field", "images");
uploadFormData.append(
  "path",
  `cars/${user ? `private/${user.username}` : "public"}/${
    res.data.data.id
  }`,
);
await fetcher.post(`/upload`, uploadFormData)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that’s a pain of upload, the images get added to database as soon as they processed, so the least size image gets appended first.

What would I do in this case, is:
I’ve would handle upload and entry creations in separate requests, e.g. use /api/upload route for uploading images, then use /api/whatever route to create entry, so you can provide uploaded file id’s as array of [{id}] to get them in the order you want…

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought strapi had such a function, but I didn't find it.  By the way, if you are interested, I will tell you how I solved this problem.  When I add a picture to the date form I generate a name which is unique and has id order in it, so I decided to just sort the images before displaying them + The maximum number of images is 6, so I think it will be faster than  loading them one by one.  although, on the other hand, sorting will always take place and take some time, and sooner or later it will exceed the time I would spend on uploading pictures one by one.

Comment: I thought and realized that your solution is the best for additional reasons, because I also have a form to edit car, so if I want to change the order there, I just need to update the array of id files. Thank you so much )